# Issue with DD4T project setup with Java

Tags: dd4t, java

Can anyone suggest me the exact steps required to setup a new DD4T java project with eclipse and tomcat. I have followed the steps suggest at https://code.google.com/p/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion/wiki/31_Quickstart. I have added the dependencies required. I can build the project successfully.
When I try to run the project from eclipse by adding to a tomcat instance it is showing error status code as 404. Please suggest..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're getting a 404, then most likely your web.xml servlet mappings are wrong or MVC routings are not configured correctly.  This is not likely a DD4T setup issue, but rather a Spring MVC setup issue.  My suggestion is for you to take a few steps back and first get a base MVC application working, and after that add on DD4T.